# How to dash a whole row if a cell is OK?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have a cell that can be `OK`, `ERROR` or `WARNING`. When it is changed to `OK` I want to modify the whole row in some way. I was thinking about to dash all cells.

Is it possible? Or is there something I can do to see the whole row in a different way automatically?

Comment: By "whole line" do you mean entire row?

Comment: @Tyler: Yes, I meant row. Sorry.

Comment: Read with answer on [so]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3860310/1536038

Answer (score 1):

New Google Sheets allows the use of a custom formula for conditional formatting, so for example:

[image: WA8916 example]

This is using highlighting for the modification as I am not sure what you mean by `dash all cells`.